# Windows 7 hibernates by itself

Tags: windows-7, battery, hibernate

I have Windows 7 Pro 64-bit installed on a Lenovo Thinkpad X120e, and it is set up so that it will go into hibernation when the battery is too low. Sometimes, the computer hibernates by itself, and when I boot it again it tells me that it hibernated because of low battery. The problem is, the battery is not low or damaged or anything. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this type of issue is caused by either the battery (usually) or laptop (rarely) reporting that the battery capacity is 0% for just a second.  The problem may happen most often when you disconnect the power and the battery changes from charge to discharge.

The problem is that the chip in the battery is reporting the current capacity incorrectly, and the system interprets it as 0% which triggers low battery actions.  Chemically, the battery itself is fine, but the internal electronics are malfunctioning.  In almost every case I've seen this issue occur, it was corrected by replacing the battery.  If you're using a third party battery or refurbished battery, this type of issue is more common.

Comment: Is there some utility one could use to monitor the battery to verify this is the cause? I am experiencing a similar problem (http://superuser.com/questions/456172), this sound like this might be the case, and I would like to know how can I verify if I should send the UPS for inspection / repair.

Answer (score -1):

Right-click the power-icon on your system-tray and go to power-options. It contains various options regarding when should your computer hibernate, sleep, shutdown, etc. under various power-profiles i.e. plugged-in and unplugged. To test, set all settings to "Never" in the plugged-in profile and see if your machine stops hibernating. If it hibernates even then, I suspect a hardware-issue.

Comment: I wanted to try this, as it sounds reasonable, however it cannot be done, as there was is no "Never" for the Battery version of the Power profiles. Critical battery level cannot be set to lower then 10 % and Critical action cannot be set to Do nothing.

Comment: @Suma - It is not there in battery version, but should be there in the "switched-on" version. Then, you can test whether the laptop stops hibernating in at least the switched-on mode.

Comment: This link tells how should I be able to change the value under the system decided limit: http://www.howtogeek.com/58109/how-to-lower-the-critical-battery-level-to-1-in-windows-7/ (I did not try it yet)